# is necessary to use getStaticprops or SSR in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, next.js, jwt

I need to handle auth and Dashboard/page in my Next.js app.
API made with DRF, and I need to know is necessary to use getStaticProps or SSR in pages?
I prefer to use simple useContext and useState with Axios, but I'm lost and don't know if I can do things like this.

Comment: you can user ssr here, everytime user visit dasgboards, it will fetch data from api and show.

Comment: That being said you don't have to use either SSR or `getStaticProps`, it's perfectly fine to handle the auth on the client-side too. It's really up to you.